# Tensorflow/Keras, How to convert tf.feature_column into input tensors?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have the following code to average embeddings for list of item-ids.
(Embedding is trained on review_meta_id_input, and used as look up for pirors_input and for getting average embedding)

```
 review_meta_id_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='review_meta_id')
 priors_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='priors') # array of ids
 item_embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
     input_dim=100,      # max number
     output_dim=self.item_embedding_size,
     name='item')

 review_meta_id_embedding = item_embedding_layer(review_meta_id_input)
 selected = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(review_meta_id_embedding, priors_input)
 non_zero_count =  tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(priors_input, axis=1), tf.float32)
 embedding_sum = tf.reduce_sum(selected, axis=1)
 item_average = tf.math.divide(embedding_sum, non_zero_count)
```

I also have some feature columns such as.. 
(I just thought feature_column looked cool, but not many documents to look for..)

```
  kid_youngest_month = feature_column.numeric_column("kid_youngest_month")
     kid_age_youngest_buckets = feature_column.bucketized_column(kid_youngest_month, boundaries=[12, 24, 36, 72, 96])
```

I'd like to define `[review_meta_id_iput, priors_input, (tensors from feature_columns)]` as an input to keras Model.

something like:

```
 inputs = [review_meta_id_input, priors_input] + feature_layer
 model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=o)
```

In order to get tensors from feature columns, the closest lead I have now is

```
fc_to_tensor = {fc: input_layer(features, [fc]) for fc in feature_columns}
```

from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17170

However I'm not sure what the `features` are in the code.
There's no clear example on https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/input_layer either.

How should I construct the `features` variable for `fc_to_tensor` ?

Or is there a way to use `keras.layers.Input` and `feature_column` at the same time?

Or is there an alternative than tf.feature_column to do the bucketing as above? then I'll just drop the feature_column for now;

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you desire could be achieved through following steps.

This works in TF 2.0.0-beta1, but may being changed or even simplified in further reseases.

Please check out issue in TensorFlow github repository [Unable to use FeatureColumn with Keras Functional API #27416](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27416#issuecomment-502218673). There you will find the more general example and useful comments about `tf.feature_column` and `Keras Functional API`.

Meanwhile, based on the code in your question the input tensor for feature_column could be get like this:

```
# This you have defined feauture column
kid_youngest_month = feature_column.numeric_column("kid_youngest_month")
     kid_age_youngest_buckets = feature_column.bucketized_column(kid_youngest_month, boundaries=[12, 24, 36, 72, 96])

# Then define layer
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(kid_age_youngest_buckets)

# The inputs for DenseFeature layer should be define for each original feature column as dictionary, where
# keys - names of feature columns
# values - tf.keras.Input with shape =(1,), name='name_of_feature_column', dtype - actual type of original column 
feature_layer_inputs = {}
feature_layer_inputs['kid_youngest_month'] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name='kid_youngest_month', dtype=tf.int8)

# Then you can collect inputs of other layers and feature_layer_inputs into one list 
inputs=[review_meta_id_input, priors_input, [v for v in feature_layer_inputs.values()]]

# Then define outputs of this DenseFeature layer
feature_layer_outputs = feature_layer(feature_layer_inputs)
# And pass them into other layer like any other
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(feature_layer_outputs)
# Or maybe concatenate them with outputs from your others layers
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, feature_layer_outputs])

#And probably you will finish with last output layer, maybe like this for calssification
o=tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes_number, activation='softmax', name='sequential_output')(combined)

#So you pass to the model:

model_combined = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[s_inputs, [v for v in feature_layer_inputs.values()]], outputs=o)
```

Also note. In model `fit()` method you should pass info which data sould be used for each input.

One way, if you use `tf.data.Dataset`, take care that you have used the same names for features in `Dataset` and for keys in `feature_layer_inputs` dictionary

Other way use explicite notation like:

```
model.fit({'review_meta_id_input': review_meta_id_data, 'priors_input': priors_data, 'kid_youngest_month': kid_youngest_month_data},
          {'outputs': o},
          ...
         )
```